# Unity Trash icon error /home/trash no such file or directory after upgrd to 14.10

Tags: unity, icons, trash

I have a minor buggy problem after I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 14.10.
When I click on the Trash icon, on Unity side bar I get the following error:
" /home/trash:: No such file or directory"

I can still use Nautilus to see the trash bin and empty the files etc.
But the Icon and link to the trash in not correct and it would be nice to fix this.
I have found the following in my home directory
 ~/.local/share/Trash
So it looks like the reference to the trash icon is not pointing to the correct path.
Please let me know where I can fix this.
I did look through .config but can't seem to find where or how to re-link/edit the icon to the correct path.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an already [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1217647) bug. A workaround is to create a directory named `trash:` that points to `.local/share/Trash` in your `/home`. So, while you are in `/home`, run:

> `ln -s /home/<user-name>/.local/share/Trash/ ~/trash:`

by replacing `<user-name>`with your actual username.